# FirebaseException ([core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()) but I Have just initializated it

Tags: firebase, flutter

it works since now, I get this problem sometimes but I am sure to initializate firebase.
It run normally without debug mode but with debug mode it give me this error.
I try to change database rules too but not works.
This is my Main code:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (user != null) {
            if (Platform.isAndroid) {
              return const MaterialApp(
                home: ChooseMarco(),
              );
            } else {
              return const CupertinoApp(
                home: ChooseMarcoIOS(),
              );
            }
          } else {
            if (Platform.isAndroid) {
              return MaterialApp(
                home: SignInAndroid(),
              );
            } else {
              return CupertinoApp(
                home: SignInIOS(),
              );
            }
          }
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

What can I do?
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `await` in front of `Firebase.initializeApp()`. This is my example for it.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(App());
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks. But i don't understand why with futurebuilding it gave me problem